# Guessing a number with if-else statement

Tags: powershell, scripting, windows-scripting

I have write a short powershell script for a guessing number game. This looks like following:

```
clear-host

$Guess = "11"

$response=read-host "Enter your guess"

if ($response -eq $guess)
{ 
    write-host "Congratulations"
}
else {
    write-host "Try again"
}
```

Now, if I want to do in such way that after a certain number of times wrong guessing for example, 3 times wrong guessing the program will exit. How I can do this? Can you please shade some light on that issue?

Comment: you will need a loop

Comment: i am no able to do that thing. can you please show me?

Comment: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_example_loop.htm

Comment: should I use the do- until loop before the IF statement???

Comment: you should use it around it. Like put the read-host and the if inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with a while loop

```
$count = 0
$answered = $false
while ($count -lt 3 -and $answered -eq $false) {
    clear-host

    $Guess = "11"

    $response=read-host "Enter your guess"

    if ($response -eq $guess)
    { 
        $answered = $true
        write-host "Congratulations"
    }
    else {
        write-host "Try again"
    }
    $count++
}
```